# Write a program to make money change

Tags: python

I want to write a program that gives me the lowest number of bills possible to make a change in LBP.

```
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])

if n%100==0:
   print(n//100, " LBP ", 10**5)

elif n//100!=0 and n%50==0:
     print(n//100, " LBP ", 10**5)
     m = n-100*(n//100)
     print(m//50, " LBP ", 5*(10**4))

elif n//100!=0 or n//50!=0 and n%20==0:
     print(n//100, " LBP ", 10**5)
     m = n-100*(n//100)
     print(m//50, " LBP ", 5*(10**4))
     o = m - 50*(m//50)
     print(o//20, " LBP ", 2*(10**4))

elif n//100!=0 or n//50!=0 or n//20!=0 and n%10==0:
     print(n//100, " LBP ", 10**5)
     m = n-100*(n//100)
     print(m//50, " LBP ", 5*(10**4))
     o = m - 50*(m//50)
     print(o//20, " LBP ", 2*(10**4))
     p = o - 20*(o//20)
     print(p//10, " LBP ", (10**4))

elif n//100!=0 or n//50!=0 or n//20!=0 or n//10!=0 and n%5==0:
     print(n//100, " LBP ", 10**5)
     m = n-100*(n//100)
     print(m//50, " LBP ", 5*(10**4))
     o = m - 50*(m//50)
     print(o//20, " LBP ", 2*(10**4))
     p = o - 20*(o//20)
     print(p//10, " LBP ", (10**4))
     q = p - 10*(p//10)
     print(n//5, " LBP ", 5*(10**3))

elif n//100!=0 or n//50!=0 or n//20!=0 or n//10!=0 or n//5!=0 and n%1==0:
     print(n//100, " LBP ", 10**5)
     m = n-100*(n//100)
     print(m//50, " LBP ", 5*(10**4))
     o = m - 50*(m//50)
     print(o//20, " LBP ", 2*(10**4))
     p = o - 20*(o//20)
     print(p//10, " LBP ", (10**4))
     q = p - 10*(p//10)
     print(n//5, " LBP ", 5*(10**3))
     r = q - 5*(q//10)
     print(n-m-o-p-q-r, " LBP ", 10**3)
```

It doesn't work for some numbers, for example 134.
Can you please help me fix it or suggest any other way to write it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does it do if you give it 134?

Comment: It gives me 1  LBP  100000
0  LBP  50000
1  LBP  20000 I don't want it to give me 0 LBP. Plus there's 1 10000 and 4 1000 that don't appear.

Comment: I suggest you fix your indentation. As posted, this will not run.

Comment: I fixed it khelwood

Comment: @Loulou EC Can you show some examples of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: I fixed my code khelwood

Comment: Yes for example in the terminal when I write 92 it should give me:
1 LBP 50,000
2 LBP 20,000
2 LBP 1,000

Comment: It is like you're decomposing the number into factors of 100, 50, 20, 10, 5 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def lbp(num):
    count = {}
    for bill in [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1]:
        count[bill] = num // bill
        num %= bill
    return {k: v for k, v in count.items() if v > 0}


import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])

for bill, count in sorted(lbp(n).items(), reverse=True):
    print(count, ' LBP ', bill*1000)
```

Using loops and functions it can be cleaned up quite a bit.

Comment: Fantastic! But how can I make the output not include 0 bills. For example, if I input 76, the output is 0 LBP 100000
1 LBP 50000
1 LBP 20000
0 LBP 10000
1 LBP 5000
1 LBP 1000 and I don't want the 0's

Comment: @LoulouEC I updated my answer so it will no longer include 0 bills.